# Read an environment variable from a .NET appSettings.json file in an Angular service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular-services

I have a service which requests some JSON data from a Web API:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ReviewService {
    private actionUrl: string;

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        this.actionUrl = 'http://api.dc-shop.com/review';
    }

    public GetAll = (): any => {
        return this._http.get(this.actionUrl)
            .map(x => x.json());
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid hard coding the API address in the constructor and instead read a setting from `appSettings.json` which I can use for the action URL at startup for production and localhost servers.

What is the best way of doing this in ASP.NET MVC Core?

Comment: Yes, I have a appSettings.json file in my MVC project where I define the API address so that I can test it on localhost

Comment: Why not to store this in some global service? and call every time from there

Comment: Thanks for that link I can see having a separate Angular2 environment file would work.

Comment: Thanks Dale that has answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options I can think of:

1) Put the configuration in `environment.ts` as well as `appSettings.json` - access to this is built into angular.

2) Step 1 of your service loads `appSettings.json` using a straight-forward `http.get` and then uses the config from it load the required data.

Example of environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
    apiUrl: 'http://api.dc-shop.com',
    mode: 'prod'
};
```

Example usage:

```
import { environment } from './environment';    
constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.actionUrl = environment.apiUrl + '/review';
}
```

Comment: I ended up going for option 1 and having a separate environment.ts. The appsettings.json file is not copied to wwwroot and could contain connection strings so it was not the best solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this  by  using [Angular Http Intercepter](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)

Add the  **http://api.dc-shop.com** prefix in each request.

Example Code:

Write an Request Intercepter  in Your Angular App:

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let req_url = req.url
    req.clone({url:`http://api.dc-shop.com/${req_url}`})
    return next.handle(req);
    }


}
```

And in your Main Module:

```
   export const httpInterceptorProviders = [
      {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: RequestInterceptor, multi: true},
    } 

   @NgModule({
       providers: [...,httpInterceptorProviders]
    })
```

If you want to config your prefix url in different environment:

Your can define it in your `environment.xx.ts` under  `/src/environments`

And Define the build config in angular.json

```
 ....
 "configurations": {
   "api": {
    ....
       "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.api.ts"
            }
          ]
     }
   ....
 }
 ...
```

And when your build your app ,

just add configuration

```
 ng build   --configuration=api
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Better would be If you provide example too.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers